# Get min and max String of list

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I've got a `List<String> list` and want to get the first and last String of that list in alphabetical order. I want to solve that problem using the power of Java 8 and Streams with collectors.

This does not work:

```
String first = list.stream().collect(Collectors.minBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

It gives me a compiler error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional to String

Can you explain why and show me the best way to do what I want to do?

Comment: If your list of strings cannot contain duplicates, you could just use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead.

Comment: By the way you might use `Optional<String> opt = list.stream().min(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Collectors.minBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#minBy-java.util.Comparator-) and [`Collectors.maxBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy-java.util.Comparator-) return an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html): if the Stream is empty, an empty `Optional` is returned; otherwise, an `Optional` containing the result is returned.

If you want to have a default value (or just `null`) when the Stream is empty, you can call `orElse`.

```
String first = list.stream().collect(minBy(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)).orElse(null);
```

Also, if you're sure the Stream is not empty, you can directly call `get()` and retrieve the value.

---

As a side-note, you can also return the minimum value by calling [`Collections.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-) (resp. [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-)):

```
String first = Collections.min(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

without the need of creating a Stream pipeline. Note that this will throw an exception if the list is empty.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is quite clear. So is [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#minBy-java.util.Comparator-): `Collector.minBy()` produces a result of type `Optional<T>`, i.e. `Optional<String>` in your case.

Why? Because it can't return any string if the stream happens to be empty. So you need to [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) the String value out of the [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) returned by `collect()`.

Note that get() will throw an exception is the stream was empty, and a min value coult thus not be found. If that's what you want because an empty list is never supposed to happen, then fine. Otherwise, you should use orElse() or orElseThrow() to return an alternative default value, or throw another exception.

Comment: Except you don't want to use get(); that will throw if the list is empty.  You want to use one of the safe methods like orElse, orElseThrow, ifPresent, etc.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Unless you *want* it to fail on empty list.

Comment: I agree in general, of course. But if the goal is to throw, because an empty list is not supposed to happen, then get() does the right thing already. That seems to be case here.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you want both min and max from the list. There is no standard collector that does this but you can create your own:

```
class ExtremesCollector<T> {
    private final Comparator<T> comparator;
    private Optional<T> min = Optional.empty();
    private Optional<T> max = Optional.empty();

    public static Collector<T> collector(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        return Collector.of(() -> new ExtremesCollector(comparator),
            ExtremesCollector::accept, ExtremesCollector::combine);
    }

    public Optional<T> getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public Optional<T> getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    private ExtremesCollector(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    private void accept(T value) {
        if (!min.isPresent() || comparator.compare(min.get(), value) < 0)
            min = Optional.of(value):
        if (!max.isPresent() || comparator.compare(max.get(), value) > 0)
            max = Optional.of(value):
    }

    private ExtremesCollector combine(ExtremesCollector other) {
        if (other.min.isPresent())
            accept(other.min.get());
        if (other.max.isPresent())
            accept(other.max.get());
    }
}
```

This is used as you would expect:

```
ExtremesCollector extremes = myList.parallelStream()
    .collect(ExtremesCollector.collector(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
extremes.getMax().ifPresent(System.out::println);
extremes.getMin().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Really the only advantage of this over using the built in `min` and `max` methods is efficiency.